# Delphi correct use of tasks

Tags: delphi

**SITUATION**

To better understand the PPL and how a `Task` works I tried to make a very easy program in which, once you have clicked a button, a `ListBox` is filled with a list of directories in the disk.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var proc: ITask;
begin

 //Show that something is going to happen
 Button1.Caption := 'Process...';

 proc := TTask.Create(

  procedure
  var strPath: string;
      sl: TStringDynArray;
  begin

   if (DirectoryExists('C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents\uni\maths')) then
    begin
     ListBox1.Items.Clear;
     sl := TDirectory.GetDirectories('C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents\uni\maths',
     TSearchOption.soAllDirectories, nil);

     for strPath in sl do
      begin
       ListBox1.Items.Add(strPath);
      end;

     //At the end of the task, I restore the original caption of the button 
     Button1.Caption := 'Go';
     Label1.Caption := 'Finished';

    end;
  end

 );

 proc.Start;

end;
```

The folder `maths` you can see above is not very huge and the task takes about 3 seconds to execute. The task is declared as follows:

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    //... other published things var ...
  private
    proc: ITask;
  public
    //... public var ...
  end;
```

---

**PROBLEM**

When I work (for example) with `C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents` I have a very big amount of folders and the program takes up to 3 minutes before filling the ListBox.

If I closed the program (while the task is still running) having only the code above, from what I have understood reading online, the task will still run until he hasn't finished. Am I correct?

```
procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
 proc.Cancel;
end;
```

I thought that I could add this code to improve the safety of the program. Is that enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TTask` runs in a worker thread.  As shown, your Task code is not thread-safe.  You **must** sync with the main UI thread when accessing UI controls.

You are not managing your `proc` variable correctly.  You have a `proc` variable declared as a member of your `TForm3` class, but you *also* have a local `proc` variable declared in your `Button1Click()` method.  The method is assigning the new task to the local variable, the class member is never being assigned.

And no, it is not enough to just call `Cancel()` on the `TTask`.  Your task procedure needs to periodically check if the task has been cancelled so it can stop its work (the only way to cancel `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` is to have its predicate filter raise an exception).

Since `TDirectory.GetDirectories()` does not exit until *all* directories have been located and stored in the returned list, if you need a more responsible task and a faster UI result, or if you just want to reduce memory usage, you should use `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()` in a manual loop instead, then you can update the UI and check for cancel in between loop iterations as needed.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    //...
  private
    proc: ITask;
    procedure AddToListBox(batch: TStringDynArray);
    procedure TaskFinished;
  public
    //...
  end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(proc) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Task is already running');
    Exit;
  end;

  //Show that something is going to happen
  Button1.Caption := 'Process...';

  proc := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    var
      strFolder: string;
      sr: TSearchRec;
      batch: TStringDynArray;
      numInBatch: Integer;
    begin
      try
        strFolder := 'C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents\uni\maths\';
        if FindFirst(strFolder + '*.*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
        try
          TThread.Queue(nil, ListBox1.Items.Clear);
          batch := nil;

          repeat
            Form3.proc.CheckCanceled;

            if (sr.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
            begin
              if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
              begin
                if not Assigned(batch) then
                begin
                  SetLength(batch, 25);
                  numInBatch := 0;
                end;

                batch[numInBatch] := strFolder + sr.Name;
                Inc(numInBatch);

                if numInBatch = Length(batch) then
                begin
                  AddToListBox(batch);
                  batch := nil;
                  numInBatch := 0;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
        finally
          FindClose(sr);
        end;

        if numInBatch > 0 then
        begin
          SetLength(batch, numInBatch)
          AddToListBox(batch);
        end;
      finally
        TThread.Queue(nil, TaskFinished);
      end;
    end
  );
  proc.Start;
end;

procedure TForm3.AddToListBox(batch: TStringDynArray);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(batch);
    end
  end);
end;

procedure TForm3.TaskFinished;
begin
  proc := nil;
  Button1.Caption := 'Go';
  Label1.Caption := 'Finished';
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(proc) then
  begin
    proc.Cancel;
    repeat
      if not proc.Wait(1000) then
        CheckSynchronize;
    until proc = nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: For large directory lists (or any large list) it may be useful to batch updates to the UI.  The task can accumulate a few dozen items and then update in batches using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` on the listbox - updating every item can be a performance hog.  This also naturally produces a nice interval to call `CheckCanceled` so that `.Cancel` will allow `proc.Wait()` to return in a timely manner.

Comment: I considered that before posting, but that raises issues with memory management and object ownership.  But I have updated my answer.

Comment: Didn't expect you to update your answer - was just leaving it for OP as an idea.  I didn't include it in my answer either for the same reason; it all gets complicated rather quickly. +1, in any case!

Comment: Ok now I have a better idea about the TTask and also thank you for suggesting a better method than GetDirectories()

Comment: I believe your edit killed the code... passing batch variable to a anonymous method and then immediately resetting its value.

Comment: @DarianMiller I have updated my code to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manipulate UI objects in threads other than the main thread.  You must synchronize access to these objects.  All types of unexpected (ie: bad) things start to happen when you have multiple threads trying to operate on UI objects simultaneously.

For example - extract the work you intend to do with the resulting directory listing once you have it and put it into a separate method :

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateDirectoryList(AList : TStringDynArray);
var
  strPath : string;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    ListBox1.Items.Clear;
    for strPath in AList do ListBox1.Items.Add(strPath);
  ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;      
  Button1.Caption := 'Go';
  Label1.Caption := 'Finished';
end;
```

Then, have your task queue this method for the UI thread to execute when it completes its long-running work :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var proc: ITask;
begin
  Button1.Caption := 'Process...';
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  proc := TTask.Create(
    procedure
    var
      sl: TStringDynArray;
    begin
      if (DirectoryExists('C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents\uni\maths')) then
        begin
          sl := TDirectory.GetDirectories('C:\Users\albertoWinVM\Documents\uni\maths',
                                      TSearchOption.soAllDirectories, nil);
          TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
                             begin
                               UpdateDirectoryList(sl);
                             end);
        end;
    end);
  proc.Start;
end;
```

This way, your task is operating solely on private data which it then returns to the main thread when it is complete - nobody steps on each others toes.

When cancelling the thread it is not enough to simply call `ITask.Cancel` - you must wait for it to finish.  Ideally, your task should periodically call `.CheckCanceled` so that it can finish in a timely manner if and when it is cancelled externally.  `CheckCanceled` will raise `EOperationCancelled` if the task has been cancelled so you should handle that and exit as soon as possible.  If you search as @Remy has suggested, this becomes much easier since you have opportunity at each loop iteration to check for cancellation.